# breakpoint in eclipse for appengine

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, google-app-engine, pydev

I have pydev on eclipse and would like to debug handlers. I put breakpoint on a handler and start project in debug mode. When I click on the hyperlink corresponding to handler the control does not come back to breakpoint. Am I missing something here?
Also the launch is for google app engine application in python.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I change the -Arguments tab-in debug configuration in eclipse to datastore_path="${project_loc}/tmp/myapp_datastore"

WARNING  2009-06-09 21:46:23,671 datastore_file_stub.py:404] Could not read datastore data from F:\eclipse\workspace\checkthis\tmp\carpoolkaro_datastore
WARNING  2009-06-09 21:46:23,671 datastore_file_stub.py:404] Could not read datastore data from c:\docume~1\abc\locals~1\temp\dev_appserver.datastore.history

Comment: This is not an error, only a warning ! The system tell you that it has not found previous datastore (logic or a first execution)

You are not obliged to specify the datastore path, by default the system with put the datastore file in the temp directory. But this is a good practice in order to store data between two executions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using eclipse with PyDev with appengine and I debug all the time, it's completely possible !

What you have to do is start the program in debug, but you have to start the dev_appserver in debug, not the handler directly. The main module you have to debug is:

```
<path_to_gae>/dev_appserver.py
```

With program arguments:

```
--datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore <your_app>
```

I hope it help

Comment: tht helps, i was wondering the path of storage on windows XP, not found yet

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to debug is to use the builtin python module `pdb` and debug from the shell.

Just set the trace in the handler you want to debug.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

How do U run the server, from within the eclipse or from the shell. If it is from the shell, then how does eclipse know you are even running the application;

You could use an user friendly version of `pdb`, `ipdb` that also includes user friendly options like auto complete.